# Indefinite Number of Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic, join

I'm trying to join a table with itself indefinite number of times.
Columns are:

```
+----------+---------+         +--------+--------+--------+---+-----+-----+-----+
| ClientID |  Data   |         | Client |  Data  | Client | * | Cli |  *  | ... |
+----------+---------+         +--------+--------+--------+---+-----+-----+-----+
|  7       | *data*  |         |    7   | *data* |    8   | * |  9  |  *  |     |
|  7       | *data*  |         |    7   | *data* |    8   | * |  9  |  *  |     |
|  8       | *data*  |    ->   |    7   | *data* |    8   | * |  9  |  *  |     |
|  9       | *data*  |         |    7   | *data* |   ...  | * | ... |     |     |
|  ...     |  ...    |         |   ...  |   ...  |        | * |     |     |     |
+--------------------+         +--------+--------+--------+--+-----+------+-----+
```

I dont know the number of the distinct clients and I need the tables FULLy JOINed. I try not to use dynamic SQL, which I suspect would be the easiest way of doing this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show more about the structure of the table and its rows? Do just want to select the same row all over again?

Comment: Show us desired output

Comment: First I want to join the table with itself for every DISTINCT number from [ClientId]. Joined as many times as the distinct [ClientId]'s are.

Comment: And desired output is?

Comment: Whatever your want to achieve (except from just testing what happens), I don't think you'll need to make a join for every record in initial full join...

Comment: The input is a list of "Clients". I want every client with its corresponding set of data on a new column, only one client per column.
@Luv: I dont understand your question.
I'm sorry for being unclear.

Comment: If you want a dynamic number of columns you need dynamic SQL. There is no way around that.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: maybe you're right. I got misled by the JOIN clause's ability to add rows to a table. I thought running the proper JOIN operation multiple time would resolve my problem. Am I right or really the only option is dynamic SQL? Thank you all for the answers.

Comment: so you want a dynamic number of columns based on the number of times the client id shows up in the table, or do you want to just concatenate the data together?

Comment: I need dynamic number of columns. A data set take from a table for one client and FULLy joined next to the data set of another client taken from the same table. Concatenation wont help me.
Thank you for the suggestions so far.

Comment: Dynamic SQL it is.
Please close the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
select distinct clientid, 
stuff((select ','+DATA 'data()'
from [table] t1
where t1.clientid=t2.clientid
for xml path('')),1,1,'')
from [table] t2
```